# Python - unichr() - 'charmap' codec can't encode character

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I would like to ask you for help. I have to decode unicode decimal to chars, but I am not decoding only clasisc letters, I am decoding special characters like: ؋,лв and some more ¥ and it doesn't work - it says : 'charmap' codec can't encode character. Can you help me?

I have to work with all symbols of currency from this page: http://www.xe.com/symbols.php, thank you.

Edit:
For example I need to get from decimal number 1547 symbol "؋".

Answer (score 2):

It helps to provide an example like the following.  This makes it clear about the operating environment (OS and Python version):

```
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(unichr(1547))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u060b' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

The problem is not with conversion, but with printing.  In the above case, the Windows console is using `cp437` encoding, and that doesn't support the character being printed.

The conversion works correctly, `c` contains a Unicode character, and it is the `AFGHANI SIGN`.

```
>>> c = unichr(1547)
>>> c
u'\u060b'
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.name(c)
'AFGHANI SIGN'
```

If you want it to print correctly, one way is to use an IDE `PythonWin` from the `pywin32` extensions that supports UTF-8 encoded output:

```
PythonWin 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.
Portions Copyright 1994-2008 Mark Hammond - see 'Help/About PythonWin' for further copyright information.
>>> unichr(1547)
u'\u060b'
>>> print(unichr(1547))
؋
```

Another is to write the output to a UTF-8-encoded file, and open the result in Notepad:

```
with io.open('out.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(unichr(1547)+unichr(402)+unichr(165))
```

Output file:

```
؋ƒ¥
```